# Micro SD mobile 128 GB size limit overcome

Tags: sd-card

Should I partition a larger than mobile size limit 
 microSD card would all' partitions still be  accepted by OS (Android) ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no 128GB limit (neither on sd-card nor on file-system level).

The only hard limit is if or if not microSDXC cards (sd-cards starting with 64GB) are supported.

The other "limits" are usually just a notice from the manufacturer that the device has been tested with such a card (because larger were not available at that time).

Therefore creating multiple partitions does not make much sense from my point of view.

Comment: Being recognized as 128 gb only microsd as worst imaginable scenario involving a 512 gb microsd and mobile phone  ?